# Weird behaviour with SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datetime

This happened today and it's the weirdest thing.

I'm using Entity Framework + LINQ to insert DB Values. There is a datetime column and it was working until 2016/04/01.

Today, when i insert some rows and tried to select them with:

```
Where BulletingDate = Convert(DateTime, '2016-03-01 00:00:00')
```

This works, but somehow now when i tried to insert values with this:

```
a.BulletingDate = DateTime.Parse(txtBulletinDate.Text);
entities.Auctions.Add(a);
entities.SaveChanges();
```

It adds datetime like: 2016-01-04 00:00:00.000

But Bulletin Date Text is: 2016-04-01 00:00:00

I can't seem to figure out.

Please Help.

Comment: If you've got a value in a specific format, I suggest you explicitly put that format in using `DateTime.ParseExact`...

Comment: It's likely the server and application are using different Locale's. As Jon states, you should always be specific with date times especially on a distributed application.

Answer (score 1):

Date formats are notoriously fragile; it's very easy for queries that you think are running YYYY-MM-DD to suddenly start doing YYYY-DD-MM or similar over something as minor as a different user logging in to the terminal.

*Don't* rely on dates passed into databases as strings being parsed exactly as you expect. Pass them in as date objects and you'll get much better results.

Answer (score 0):

The [datetime type in SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) uses fractional seconds. That's the .000 on the end.

If you can, I suggest switching to [datetime2 in SQL Server 2008 and up](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx), which has *optional* fractional seconds. If you don't need to track fractions of a second, then you can use datetime2(0). It plays nicely with C# DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

Bouild your datetime object like this

DateTime x = new DateTime(2016,01,04);//year month day

so you dont have problems when passing it to entity framework

also if your string is in this format "20140104 00:00:00" you should be safe too (at least MSSQL have no problem with that format, not sure if C# is cool too)